# Присоединиться к проекту на Ruby (Где?)

Tags: ruby

Совсем недавно начал изучать этот замечательный, на мой взгляд, язык. В качестве практики хотелось бы присоединиться к какому-нибудь некоммерческому проекту. Вопрос мой заключается в том, где я могу поискать подобного рода проекты?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ну, это же классика.

Посмотрите на списки проектов в разных местах, отфильтровав по языку:

- [Github](https://github.com/languages/Ruby)
- [Belios](http://developer.berlios.de/)
- [Sourceforge](http://sf.net)
- [Google code](http://code.google.com/hosting/)

И ведите на них поиск на предмет Ruby-проектов.

Comment: Двачую github, посмотрите статискику по языкам программирования и удивитесь.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ.
Из вышеописанных, использую Github и активно изучаю его функционал. Что касается поиска - как на том же github'е искать открытые проекты? Прошу прощения, за, возможно, глупый вопрос, но я себе ответ на него дать не могу:(

Comment: Я исправил ссылку на GitHub так, чтобы она вела на проекты на Ruby.

Comment: Кажется я разобрался, попробую найти что-то моего уровня =)
Огромное спасибо!

Comment: @Vladimir VG Это специфика того контингента, который участвует на GitHub. Посмотрите на Google Code и соотношения будут другие.

Comment: @lo1jke Не забудьте закрыть вопрос, чтобы не разрасталась тема и не висела в неотвеченных.

Comment: Не очевидно, как это сделать...